# How to slide a div to fill out another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'd like to make a news box which starts with a title on a background image but, when user hovers mouse over it, the news title and description fill over the background image, like news blocks [here](https://draxe.com/).

Here is what I've hacked together:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumb-box').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.news-item').removeClass('only-title')
    $(this).find('.news-item').addClass('title-and-desc');
    $(this).find('.desc-on-image').removeClass('hidden');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.news-item').removeClass('title-and-desc');
    $(this).find('.news-item').addClass('only-title');
    $(this).find('.desc-on-image').addClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.thumb-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.only-title {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title-and-desc {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-name: draw-up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes draw-up {
  from {
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  }
  to {
    padding: 1em 1em 8em 1em;
  }
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-title {
  color: black;
}

.news-title a {
  color: black;
}

.news-title a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-box img-responsive" style="background-image: url(/path/to/photo">
  <div class="news-item only-title">
    <a class="news-title" href="/article/{{$a.Slug}}">
      <h4><strong> {{$a.Title}} </strong> </h4>
      <div class="desc-on-image hidden">
        {{$a.Teaser}} ...
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is two folds:

1. It is kind of jittery. The boxes jump a bit when mouse come on them from certain angles.
2. The overlaying div jumps down as soon as it slides up.

I'm wondering how can I fix these, or how to have a more robust solution to do the same function?

Comment: and why jQuey for such thing ? do it with CSS ... and why animation ? consider transition

Comment: I used jquery, because could not find a solution to bring up a dynamically hyperlinked div on hover. Admittedly, I'm not a frontend guy.

Comment: Read a little bit about transitions. They are pretty powerful if used correctly. You can do this with CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure css solution

```css
.news-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.news-item{
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.news-item:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.news-item > img{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.news-description{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -60px; /* this sets the visible part's height */
  margin-top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.news-description h5{
  display: block;
  height: 80px; /* this is the hight of the title */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.news-description p{
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.news-item:hover .news-description{
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="news-container">

  <div class="news-item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/360/?random)">
    <div class="news-description">
      <h5>News One</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer iaculis laoreet sapien ac auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="news-item" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/400/?random)">
    <div class="news-description">
      <h5>News Two With A Slightly Longer Title</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer iaculis laoreet sapien ac auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="news-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/400/?random)" alt="" />
    <div class="news-description">
      <h5>News Item With img Tag</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer iaculis laoreet sapien ac auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

Added images to `.news-item` as an inline css style. In the stylesheet also added `background-size: cover;` for `.news-item`.

Added `img` tag inside `.news-item` and a corresponding css rules as another way of adding images.

Comment: Nice, but I need to dynamically load background images for each news-container. Also `news-description` should have some semi opaque background before hover.   How would you do that?

Comment: It's pretty easy and there are two ways of accomplishing it. 1. Set a background of a `.new-item` element. 2. Add an `<img />` inside `.news-item` element.

Comment: Edited the code snippet to show you how you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, but still the title has no background before sliding up. This make reading difficult when the image is whitish.

Comment: Edited the snippet. Try running it again. Basically  I just changed the initial background and opacity properties of `.news-item:after`. It all comes down to editing css: how should the normal state look, and how should the hovered one look.

Comment: Well, it still does not replicate what I meant. You can see the original here: https://draxe.com/

Comment: Updated the snippet. Check it out.

Comment: Great. Thank you! Just wondering how to reduce the distance between news title and its description when they are slided up?

Comment: I left comments in the css. Take a look. Basically you need to tweak two things: `.news-description` and `.news-description h5`. The downside of this approach is that the `h5` header must have a fixed height, but it's how they did it on the website that you wanted to replicate. Normally I would do it differently, in more flexible way, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

**[Relative positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=relative)**, **[overflow: hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden)**, **[Absolute Positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=absolute)**  and **[transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)**

This can be implemented without using javascript or Jquery.

The outer div `container` is given **[position: relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** and **[overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)**.

So, whatever is inside the `container`, and has more width or more height than `container` or maybe placed outside the `container` relatively, then it has ***overflown*** the `container` and stays ***hidden***.

Now, we use **[position: absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** to place the `slider` absolutely with some distance away from `top` i.e,100px. So, now it overflows it's parent div `container`. But it is hidden because of **[overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)** on its parent div `container`.

Now, using the css [**child combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), whenever the parent div `container` is hovered, we slide the `slider` up using **[transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)**.

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/400);
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slider{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  transition: top 1s;
}
.container:hover > .slider{
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='slider'>
    <h1>I will Slide</h1>
    <p>My content</p>
    <p>My content</p>
    <p>My content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Move transition to `.slider`. So it would move out smoothly too.

Comment: yeah. I just tried to imitate it with the one OP is referencing to. Anyway, I changed it.

Comment: This is nice, but one issue is that  ` background-image` is loaded dynamically, so it can not be in css.  How can I  take this into account?

Comment: Why it cannot be css?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by simply using CSS transition.

Here is an example where you can adjust easily the CSS property to have the needed effect.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.thumb-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.only-title {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  transition:1s;
  top:60%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.thumb-box:hover .only-title {
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb-box img-responsive" style="background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/)">
  <div class="news-item only-title">
    <a class="news-title" href="#">
      <h4><strong> title</strong> </h4>
      <div class="desc-on-image hidden">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ornare placerat placerat. Sed id nulla odio. Morbi lacinia ultrices velit, faucibus commodo torto
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the issue with this is that the slider does not fully cover the background image.

Comment: @Karlom we can simply adjust this, check again, it's updated ;)